# Put number separately in array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I would like to put a number separately in an array

ex.

```
$num = 345;
```

should be in an array so i can call the numbers as

```
$num[1] (which should return 4)
```

I tried `str_split($num,1)` but without succes.

Thanks

EDIT -------

After some more research `str_split($num,1)` actually did the trick.
(thanks, Crayon Violent)

Comment: i'd like to know what "without success" means because at face value, your code should work fine. You did assign it to something, right? ex: `$num=345;$num=str_split($num,1);`

Comment: I would like to push every digit into the array. So it would be like $num=array("3","4","5");

Comment: + if i use the str_split($num,1) i get the error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: right.. well your code does that just fine. `$num=345;$num=str_split($num,1);print_r($num);` prints `Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 )` so if you aren't getting that, then you have other issues, like.. using php version < 5?

Comment: okay well "trying to get property of non-object" has nothing to do with `str_split`. That sounds like what you're *really* trying to split instead of `$num` is something that doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $num = 345;
>
> $arr1 = str_split($num); print_r($arr1); //Array ( [0] => 3 [1](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-split.php) => 4
>   [2] => 5 )
>
> echo $arr1[1](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-split.php); //4

[str-split](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-split.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to get individual characters from the string, use `substr`.

```
$second_digit = substr( $num, 1, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($num >0) {
  $arr[i] = $num %10;
  $num = $num/10;
  i++
}
//this leaves the array in reverse order i.e. 543
//to flip 
array_reverse($arr);
```